# Div element not displaying in line with others

Tags: html, css, inline, display

[image: Image Showing my problem]

Div element not displaying in line with other 2 div elements present despite having the necessary space for it.

I am attempting to display a web page with 3 separate paragraphs divided into div elements, but the one on the right is seemingly stuck to the bottom of the page unless I remove the center div.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="Reviews">
      <img src="review.jpg" alt="Needledrop Review" class="Review"> Sample Text Sample
</div>
<div class="Sales">
      <img src="redcarpet.jpg" alt="JID on the Red Carpet" class="RedCarpet"> Sample Text </div>
<div class="Impact">
      <img src="dreamville.jpg" alt="JID with Dreamville members" class="Dream"> Sample
</div>
```

Here is the CSS for each div element:

```
div.Reviews {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 1.207em;
  width: 400px;
  height: 770px;
  text-align: justify;
  color: white
}
img.Review {
  vertical-align: text-top;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Number 2:

```
div.Sales {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 1.207em;
  width: 400px;
  height: 770px;
  text-align: justify;
  color: white
}

img.RedCarpet {
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Number 3:

```
div.Impact {
  float: right;
  font-size: 1.207em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 255px;
  height: 737px;
  text-align: justify;
  color: white
}
img.Dream {
  vertical-align: text-top;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: add the code in snippet

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

div.Reviews {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 1.207em;
  width: 400px;
  height: 770px;
  text-align: justify;
  color: white
}

img.Review {
  vertical-align: text-top;
  width: 100%;
}

div.Sales {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 1.207em;
  width: 400px;
  height: 770px;
  text-align: justify;
  color: white
}

img.RedCarpet {
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  width: 100%;
}

div.Impact {
  float: right;
  font-size: 1.207em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 255px;
  height: 737px;
  text-align: justify;
  color: white
}

img.Dream {
  vertical-align: text-top;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="Reviews">
    <img src="https://www.typinks.com/images/character-sketch-of-friar-laurence-in-romeo-and-juliet.webp" alt="Needledrop Review" class="Review"> Sample Text Sample
  </div>
  <div class="Sales">
    <img src="https://www.typinks.com/images/role-of-fate-in-romeo-and-juliet.webp" alt="JID on the Red Carpet" class="RedCarpet"> Sample Text </div>
  <div class="Impact">
    <img src="https://www.typinks.com/images/along-with-the-raptors.webp" alt="JID with Dreamville members" class="Dream"> Sample
  </div>
</div>
```

add a parent div with `display:flex` to align in horizontal

Comment: Please explain your code to make  it  helpful.

Comment: more about flexbox: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Comment: Please don't use w3schools as a source, https://w3fools.com. Also, I meant in an edit.